# How to avoid defining the whole template class in header file

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, templates

I have class like this:

```
template <typename T>
class C
{
public:
    C(T t): t{t} {}
    void publicMethodA() { privateMethodA(); }
    void publicMethodB() {}
    void publicMethodC() {}
    // ...

private:
    void privateMethodA() { t.call(); /* only one place that uses t member */ }
    void privateMethodB() {}
    // ...

    T t;
};
```

In this example I need template field `t` in only ONE place (in `privateMethodA`) and it forces me to define each method in the header file (but they do not use `t` member). How can I avoid this? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Put all things that don't depend on T in a base class, the template stuff in a derived class.

Answer (score 5):

You can put everything that does not depend on `T` in a base class and inherit from it. Anyhow, already the fact that the class is a template, but has many methods that do not depend on the template parameter suggests that you are putting stuff inside a single class that better belongs into seperate ones.

Comment: Um... The other way around would not work, since both classes would need to be templates, and we're back to square one ;)

Comment: @Quentin yes, I have to admit that I was a bit confused while writing. Removed that nonsense stuff